# OpenCV cv2.VideoCapture(0) is not working well with webcam

Tags: raspbian, python, opencv

I am trying to use a USB webcam for a computer vision project that outputs the diminations of moving object. I installed `openCV` and tried my `python` code which it worked perfect on my PC, but when I ran it in my `raspberry pi` and the output was unexpected so I took a video output with `cv2.imshow("video output", frame)` to see whats going on and saw some thing strange. the video was flickering with some part red and some part blue.
[image: output of my video feed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was from the video source. The webcam was not compatible with OpenCV Although it worked with some other computer video input package very well